# parsing a text file with first line all 1's and second line all 2's

Tags: c++, parsing, text-files, token

i have created a program which will take a file read a text file line-by-line, and separate out the individual words in each line (as separated by blanks).
now i want to be able to edit the code so that all the tokens for the first line will be all 1's and all the tokens for the second line will be 2's
if any one could help me with this please
down below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512;
const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20;
const char* const DELIMITER = " ";
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string filename;
  // create a file-reading object
 /*std::ifstream file1("file1.txt", ios_base::app);
std::ifstream file2("file2.txt");

std::ofstream combinedfile("combinedfile.txt");
combinedfile << file1.rdbuf() << file2.rdbuf();*/

  ifstream fin;
  //enter in file name combinedfile.txt
  cout <<"please enter file name (including .txt)";
  cin >> filename ;
  fin.open(filename); // open a file
  if (!fin.good()) 
    return 1; // exit if file not found

  // read each line of the file
  while (!fin.eof())
  {
    // read an entire line into memory
    char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
    fin.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

    // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
    int n = 0; // a for-loop index

    // array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
    const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0

    // parse the line
    token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
    if (token[0]) // zero if line is blank
    {
      for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
      {
        token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
        if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
      }
    }

    // process (print) the tokens
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
      cout << "Token[" << i << "] = " << token[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

so the output should be like this:

```
Token[1] = This
Token[1] = course
Token[1] = provides
Token[1] = detailed
Token[1] = coverage
Token[1] = of
Token[1] = the
Token[1] = concepts
Token[1] = and
Token[1] = syntax

Token[2] = Coverage
Token[2] = includes
Token[2] = inheritance,
Token[2] = overloaded
Token[2] = operators,
Token[2] = overloaded
Token[2]= default
Token[2] = operators,
```

Comment: What do you mean with "1's" and "2's"? Could you please provide some more information what you exactly want to do?

Comment: so basically u know how with tokens they can count up to whatever number u set it to. I want it to just output Token[1] for the first line of my text file with every word having Token[1] and for the second line to use just Token[2] and for every word in that line to have Token[2]

Comment: @user2653471 still your're not making any sense, would you mind putting an example in your post ?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between words and tokens here. Do you only want to output the second ( token[1] ) for the first, and the third ( token[2] ) word for the lines?

Comment: i put an example in the post

Comment: You example does not make any sense. You are looping over the line, and would overwrite the token on every new one. That could not work!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to separate words into two containers such that the first contains words from the first line, and the second contains words from the second line, you can use vectors to store them and string streams to extract words from a line of text:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("test.txt");
    string line;
    string word;
    vector< vector<string> >  tokens(2);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < 2; ++ix)
    {    
        getline(infile, line);
        istringstream iss(line);
        while(iss >> word)
            tokens[ix].push_back(word);
    }   
}
```

Here, tokens[0] is a vector containing words from the first line, and tokens[1] contains words from the second line.

Comment: +1, but, `while(getline(infile, line))` should be used instead of for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of vectors as

```
vector<vector<string>> VEC;
```

And keep on adding words to `VEC[0]` for the first line and then increment the counter as you encounter a newline character to  point to `VEC[1]` and so on.

Comment: are there any alternatives i'm just trying to see if there is more than one way of doing it

Comment: @user2653471 ways might be more but this might be the most efficient one